# move files in a loop

Tags: linux, cp

I have files named

```
file_1_supply.csv
file_2_supply.csv
file_3_supply.csv
.......
file_30_supply.csv
```

I want to copy these files from one folder to another in Linux. The problem is there are also many other files in the directory. I want to do it by command line because the directory have a lots of file.

```
cp file_1_supply.csv /home/user/destination
```

usually I use this for copy but how to use this in a loop?

Comment: Why a loop? `cp file_*.csv /home/user/destination` should work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you only want to copy `file_1`-`file_30`:

```
cp file_{1..30}_supply.csv /home/user/destination
```

Comment: I edited the question.So actually I think I have to use `cp file_{1..30}_supply.csv /home/user/destination`

Answer (score 1):

Use `-t` flag to designate the destination

```
cp -t /home/user/destination file_*_supply.csv
```

For specific range, you can also use `find` command:

```
find -name "*file_[1-30]*" -exec cp "{}" /home/user/destination \;
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use this command

```
cp * /path/to/destination/
```

this is the easiest way to copy many files but if you want to specify files I suggests @Flohe's answer

Comment: That wouldn't work because it will copy all the files, however as mentioned, there are other files in the directory that shouldn't be copied.